# Reporting Services - Hide Matrix Column Conditionally

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

In a matrix report is it possible to hide a column based on value of the parent group?
For example, I've got a column called "value" which I'd like to hide when the column group that contains it has a specific value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. It you click on the group and edit its properties under the Visibility tab you can the visibility using an expression. For example I have a report that has a detail group and a valuetype group and I would like to only show value groups that have data in them.

I do that by setting the visibility expression for the group to the following:

=CountDistinct(Fields!ValueType.Value,"matrix1_Detail")=1 OR Max(Abs(code.GetValue(Fields!Value)))=0

When the expression code evaluates to true the column is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. It would involve writing an expression for the Visibility property for the data cell. The expression should include the InScope() function to ensure that the right column is being hidden. The expression would also reference ReportItems!textboxofcolumn.value (looking for that specific value you're after).

Go [here for more on the InScope() function](http://www.lukehayler.com/2009/07/the-inscope-function-and-the-key-to-formatting-subtotals-in-ssrs-matrix-objects/)

Let me know if you need a hand with the expression.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you'll just be left with a blank column representing the column you are trying to hide, rather than actually removing the column

Comment: @adolfgarlic, instead of doing this on the textbox, do it on the column group that  you want hidden.  I've had success with top level column groups, but I'm having difficulties with toggleable sub column groups...

Answer (score 1):

If you only set cell or column visibility (using the "hidden" property), it will leave white space there.  Like the first reply said, if you create a column group, and set visibility on the group, it works.

I broke my report up into several column groups, each grouped on the same thing.  Set the visibility equation on the middle group.  Worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to remove the rows from the dataset in SQL or filter them out in RS.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something to exclude blank columns from exported Excel sheets. What worked for me was select the entire column in the matrix by right-clicking on the top box in the designer, selecting "Show or hide based on an expression" and using an expression like:

IsNothing(Max(Fields!COLUMNNAME.Value, "DATASET"))

The column does not show on the report nor does it leave blanks in the export. No need of column groups or InScope() function, but I am using a very basic matrix that only has a single row group.